# Cmd+I randomly opens outlook.com in Chrome (not my default browser)

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, keyboard, mac

I am perplexed for a few reasons:

- My default browser is set to Vivaldi so I don't understand why clicking Cmd+I in Vivaldi sends me to outlook in Chrome
- I have set Cmd+I in Vivaldi to be "Intensify Page". When I click Cmd+I the page intensifies and I am then booted to a new Chrome window with Outlook
- When I hit Cmd+I in Chrome or anywhere else I am not booted to Outlook

I have noticed this in the past when I clicked email addresses and was redirected to Outlook (instead of Gmail which I use)

I used Outlook very briefly a while ago but have since signed out of all my accounts. I am redirected to the default outlook.live.com page with the smiling woman (no account signed in).

System (if relevant): Mac

I searched this up and found some q&a sites suggesting that I change app shortcuts in MacOS.

Comment: I don't have Vivaldi, but in general Cmd/i in a browser is "share this page" which would open your default mailer & pre-fill it with a link to the page you were on. How/where did you change the shortcut in Vivaldi? You change the Mac's default Mailer from within the Apple Mail app - Mail menu > Settings [or Preferences] > General

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> exports the current webpage to an email message. This works for me in both Vivaldi and Safari. There doesn't seem to a menu command that corresponds in either app; and I can't find anything in System Settings > Keyboard.

Your default email client may be relevant.

Comment: Safari… File menu > Share > Email this Page. [which is why I asked how the OP changed it. It might be possible in keyboard>shortcuts if done properly. The defaul mailer is likely a sperate issue.]

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, but that's not a traditional menu with a key command next to it.

Comment: ? Mojave - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsurD.png Monterey - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmFog.png

Comment: @Tetsujin Ventura, not so much... And interesting that it used to be Shift Command. P.S. Sorry, I didn't see your comment before I posted an answer.

Comment: Ermm… D'oh!! Only just noticed, pressing Cmd/Shift/4 to take the screenshot adds the Shift to the menu item, for some bizarre reason. It is just 'raw' Cmd/i normally.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the "default email reader"

Go to the Mail app and pick the settings there. Then change the "default email reader" to your preferred browser.

Comment: "Outlook in Chrome" sounds like the worst of all worlds! ;-)